# TexShop doesn't run Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, texshop

I recently updated Texshop (on a Mac running Catalina) to version 4.44. In files that I've used for a while, Bibtex doesn't run. By this I mean that when I select Bibtex in the dropdown menu (or use command-shift-B), nothing happens. No log file is produced, and none of the usual .blg or .bbl files are produced. Other options in that dropdown menu (Latex, Plain Tex, etc) start up as usual.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please look in at the BibTeX Engine section of the Engine Tab of  TeXShop->Preferences and let us know what is there. If it is blank for some reason it should be set to the default of bibtex.

Comment: The BibTeX engine is set to bibtex.

Comment: In Terminal what do the commands `which bibtex`, `which pdflatex` and `echo $PATH` return? When you say `it doesn't run bibtex` does a Console window show up and, if so, is there anything displayed in that window? Did you typeset your file before running bibtex?

Comment: I get no answer to which bibtex and which pdflatex; I've never had occasion to run either via the terminal. echo $PATH returns /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: I could typeset the file without difficulty, producing the typical stream of messages in the console. But with the console open, selecting bibtex produced absolutely nothing written to the console.

Comment: Prompted by your query about the path, I tried moving the file in question to another location (the desktop). It typeset fine and then bibtex runs as usual in that location. So I rather suspect that with the upgrade to Catalina some permissions were changed. This may be getting too particular to my computer to be worth your time and energy; although I would like to sort this out, I would also understand if you don't want to take this discussion any further.

Comment: @HerbSchulz After all that, I trashed all of the auxiliary files (.aux, .bbl, .blg) and tried again. Everything, including bibtex, ran as normal. I have no explanation, but for now the problem is solved. Thank you for your help.